# Does Windows Sever Shutdown if Items in Threadpool

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, threadpool

I want to use .net Threadpool or Task library, but I am unable to find any information on what happens to the threads if the machine is shutdown. My assumption is that all the tasks that were added and haven't been completed will be lost. However, maybe I have the wrong idea about Parallel tasks or Threadpools all together.

The scenario is simply. I add a bunch of tasks:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(doSomeWork);
```

Then someone comes in an shutdown this machine. What if the tasks are not done? Does the machine wait, or does it just shutdown? Is there a way to tell it to wait until it has been shutdown?

Comment: Have you tried it?  I mean it shouldn't be hard to load up a couple of tasks with `.Sleep(60000)` (5min) and then shutdown.

Comment: The operating system cares about *processes*, not threads.  Be sure to respond to the shutdown request that the operating system sends you, you left no breadcrumbs to guess which way is appropriate.

Comment: I tried it with ThreadPool and the tasks did in fact were lost, but I hadn't tried it yet with Task. I was hoping that there was some kind of Shutdown management built in and that I just somehow missed it in the documentation. Doesn't sound like it.

Answer (score 1):

Your app needs to specifically listen to system events indicating that the system is shutting down, but it is responsible for working out how to deal with this.

At the end of the day it *cannot* prevent shutdown in order to finish your tasks (nor should it). If your application needs to ensure tasks all complete, then it needs to somehow keep a record of which tasks completed, which tasks are still pending, so that it can resume when restarted.

See [this MSDN article on System Events for details of handling shutdown notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.sessionending%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).